# Conda install in offline mode not working

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, conda

I am trying to install a python package using `conda` in offline mode. I have to install in offline mode because of the network I am using.

The package I want to install is `mlpack`, and I am using `python3` on a Mac x64 with macOS Sierra 10.12.6. I downloaded `mlpack` from the Anaconda webstie: https://anaconda.org/ilastik/mlpack

Then I used the command

`conda install --offline -c ilastik /anaconda3/tars/mlpack-1.0.8.99-8.tar.bz2`

and I receive the following output:

`Downloading and Extracting Packages
*-None               |         | ############################################ | 100% 
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done`

When I look in anaconda3/pkgs I can see that a folder was created called `mlpack`. However, when I try to run `import mlpack` in Python, it says

```
import mlpack
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-4-edcb40cca368>", line 1, in <module>
    import mlpack

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mlpack'
```

I tried adding `-vv` to the install command and received this:

```
pn1503563$ conda install --offline -c ilastik /anaconda3/tars/mlpack-1.0.8.99-8.tar.bz2 -vv
DEBUG conda.gateways.logging:set_verbosity(148): verbosity set to 2
DEBUG conda.core.package_cache_data:__init__(549): instantiating ProgressiveFetchExtract with
  *[url=file:///anaconda3/tars/mlpack-1.0.8.99-8.tar.bz2]

DEBUG conda.core.package_cache_data:_check_writable(237): package cache directory '/anaconda3/pkgs' writable: True
DEBUG conda.core.package_cache_data:_check_writable(237): package cache directory '/Users/nstegmeier/.conda/pkgs' writable: True
DEBUG conda.core.package_cache_data:_check_writable(237): package cache directory '/anaconda3/pkgs' writable: True
DEBUG conda.core.link:__init__(157): instantiating UnlinkLinkTransaction with
  target_prefix: /anaconda3
  unlink_precs:
    <unknown>::mlpack-1.0.8.99-8
  link_precs:
    <unknown>::mlpack-1.0.8.99-8

DEBUG conda.core.package_cache_data:__init__(549): instantiating ProgressiveFetchExtract with
  <unknown>::mlpack-1.0.8.99-8

Preparing transaction: ...working... DEBUG conda.core.link:_get_python_version(630): found in current prefix python version 3.6
done
Verifying transaction: ...working... done
DEBUG conda.common.signals:signal_handler(43): registering handler for SIGABRT
DEBUG conda.common.signals:signal_handler(43): registering handler for SIGINT
DEBUG conda.common.signals:signal_handler(43): registering handler for SIGTERM
DEBUG conda.common.signals:signal_handler(43): registering handler for SIGQUIT
Executing transaction: ...working... INFO conda.core.link:_execute_actions(542): ===> UNLINKING PACKAGE: <unknown>::mlpack-1.0.8.99-8 <===
  prefix=/anaconda3

INFO conda.core.link:_execute_actions(548): ===> LINKING PACKAGE: <unknown>::mlpack-1.0.8.99-8 <===
  prefix=/anaconda3
  source=/anaconda3/pkgs/mlpack-1.0.8.99-8

done
DEBUG conda.common.signals:signal_handler(56): de-registering handler for Signals.SIGABRT
DEBUG conda.common.signals:signal_handler(56): de-registering handler for Signals.SIGINT
DEBUG conda.common.signals:signal_handler(56): de-registering handler for Signals.SIGTERM
DEBUG conda.common.signals:signal_handler(56): de-registering handler for Signals.SIGQUIT
```

The command `conda info --offline` gives

```
pn1503563$ conda info --offline

     active environment : None
       user config file : /Users/nstegmeier/.condarc
 populated config files : /Users/nstegmeier/.condarc
          conda version : 4.5.4
    conda-build version : 3.10.5
         python version : 3.6.5.final.0
       base environment : /anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64  (offline)
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch  (offline)
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/osx-64  (offline)
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch  (offline)
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64  (offline)
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch  (offline)
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/osx-64  (offline)
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch  (offline)
          package cache : /anaconda3/pkgs
                          /Users/nstegmeier/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /anaconda3/envs
                          /Users/nstegmeier/.conda/envs
               platform : osx-64
             user-agent : conda/4.5.4 requests/2.18.4 CPython/3.6.5 Darwin/16.7.0 OSX/10.12.6
                UID:GID : 507:20
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : True
```

Comment: I can't comment on the conda issues, but are you sure you don't want to use the newer (official) conda version of mlpack? https://anaconda.org/mlpack/mlpack

Answer (score 1):

As was pointed out you should use mlpack from the official mlpack repository. 
Ilastik channel has a very old version of mlpack without python bindings.

To download all packages required for offline installation run the following command:

`conda install -c mlpack -c conda-forge mlpack`

After this, you can find all the required packages archives in `<condadir>/pkgs`

Optionally add ilastik channel (`-c ilastik`) to this command if you need any packages from it.